# How to run Procfile on EC2 instance for rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-ec2, sidekiq, autoscaling

I want to run `Procfile` on EC2 instace.

Procfile content

```
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -e production
```

On local it is working, I used Foreman and below commands on local system

```
foreman start -f Procfile
foreman start
```

But for EC2 I have no idea, tried with `foreman` on EC2 but after running start command it stuck.

> Main purpose is to auto start `sidekiq` on EC2 instance with load balancer any other suggestions are also welcome.

Currently I have to start `sidekiq` manually after Auto-scaling in AWS.
sidekiq start command is written in launch-configuration script(user data) All other script commands are working except to start `sidekiq`

Any help would be appreciated.